# Who introduced the term torsion first and why

Tags: abstract-algebra, meta-math

In algebra, an element of finite order is called a torsion, and a subgroup consisting of all torsions of a group is call a torsion subgroup.
And I just got curioused about the term 'torsion'; who named it and why; because that term appears a bit randomly in math - like Euler's torsion function.
As a non-native English speaker myself, I don't see the relationship between the term and the concepts; if I'm not mistaken, torsion means twisting.

Comment: I guess it refers to the twisting of the powers, which "make a full turn" and go back to the start. Like the powers of $e^{i2\pi / n}$, which are points on the unit circle.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for the comment. May I ask you the meaning of torsion in the Euler's torsion function?